# Probability of sampling at least one member of each class

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, sampling

Suppose we have $N$ samples partitioned into $C$ classes with $N_1, ..., N_C$ the number of samples in each class.
Randomly we pick up $n$ samples. What is the probability to have every class in this selection (at least one sample from each class)

For this problem, I came up with the solution presented here (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/72858/ethan-bolker)

The total number of samples of size $n$ picked up among $N$ is $\binom{N}{n}$
Then you have $N_1$ ways to choose one sample from the first class, $N_2$ from the second,  ... $N_C$ from the last one. And finally  $\binom{N-C}{n-c}$ ways to pick up indifferently the remaining samples.

$$\frac{N_1 N_2...N_C\binom{N-C}{n-c}}{\binom{N}{n}}$$

However with $N=10 000$, $N_1=N_2=...=N_C=1000$ and $n=100$,  I get very high probabilities around $10^9$

So I thought I did a mistake and went with the complementary event "What is the probability of having at least one class that is **NOT** represented ?"
Here we will take balanced classes $N_1=N_2=...=N_C$

There are $C$ ways to choose the class that is not represented then you have $\binom{N-N_1}{n}$ ways to pick up the $n$ samples among the $C-1$ classes that are represented (population of size $N-N_1$)

So the answer of the first problem would the be
$$1- \frac{C\binom{N-N_1}{n}}{\binom{N}{n}}$$

However, once again with $N=10 000$, $N_1=N_2=...=N_C=1000$ and $n=10$ I will obtain negative or above 1 probabilities.

Could someone please tell me why these formulas are false

Comment: To fix your second approach, correctly apply [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  You only kept the first two terms in the expression when you should have had many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider for example $6$ samples, $2$ of which are blue (B1 and B2), $2$ of which are green (G1 and G2), and $2$ red (R1 and R2). Then we want to pick at least one sample from each color with $n=4$

With your initial formula, the choice $\{\text{B1,B2,G1,R1}\}$ gets counted twice! Indeed, we could first pick $\{\text{B1,G1,R1}\}$, one from each color, and then pick $\{\text{B2}\}$ from the remaining samples, or we could first pick $\{\text{B2,G1,R1}\}$, and then pick $\{\text{B1}\}$ from the remaining samples.

The bigger $n$ gets, the more incorrect double counting you do, so that you incorrectly get probabilities that exceed $1$.

---

Your second approach is also wrong due to double counting: Let's add two samples of color yellow (Y1 and Y2) to the above example. One way to not pick at least one sample from each color is the choice $\{B1, B2, G1, G2\}$. But you count this twice! Indeed, on could first pick to ignore the red color and then choose $\{B1, B2, G1, G2\}$, or one could first pick to ignore the yellow color and then choose $\{B1, B2, G1, G2\}$. Because you subtract incorrectly doubly-counted cases, you can incorrectly end up with negative probabilities.

Comment: Thank you, I then see how the formula is false. To get the correct solution, I should exclude all the intersections. Is there any easy way to get the solution ?

Comment: @LouisFOUQUET I do not immediately see any easy solution. You want to compute $$\lvert\{\text{picking each color at least once}\}\rvert = \binom Nn - \lvert\{\text{not picking some color}\}\rvert.$$ Now, $$\lvert\{\text{not picking some color}\}\rvert = \lvert\{\text{not picking color }1\}\cup \{\text{not picking color }2\}\dots\cup\{\text{not picking color }C\}\rvert\overset{\text{Def.}}=\lvert A_1\cup A_2\cup\dots\cup A_C\rvert,$$ i.e. I define $A_k = \{\text{not picking color $k$}\}$. Now you can use the inclusion-exclusion principle, but it can get quite messy as $C$ grows.